# Convertir 'int' a 'string'

Tags: c#

estoy intentando comunicar a mi arduino con Visual studio C#, todo va bien, lo unico que no logro conseguir es que el programa reconozca mi int como string, apesar de que ya le agregue el .tostring() al final de este. aqui el programa que llevo hasta ahora.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SerialPort1.Open();

    }

    private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        string Puerto = ("SerialPort1.ReadLine()").ToString();
        if (Puerto = 0) {
            MessageBox.Show("El valor actual es de 0");
        }
        else if (Puerto = 1) {
            MessageBox.Show("El valor actual es de 1");
        }
        else if (Puerto = 2) {
            MessageBox.Show("El valor actual es de 2");
        }
        else if (Puerto = 3) {
            MessageBox.Show("El valor actual es de 3");
        }

    }
}
```

}

gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Varias mejoras, que error estas recibiendo? no se que tratas de hacer con esto: ("SerialPort1.ReadLine()").ToString();, pero eso es convertir un string en string. asi que podrias ser mas claro? (es mas, readline devuelve un string

Comment: tendrías que convertir el dato, si no mal recuerdo tendría que ser con Int.Parse().

Comment: convertir de qué a qué? y además convertir por qué?

Comment: El código que muestras no compila. A parte de lo que te ha indicado ya @LeandroTuttini, el operador de comparación en C# es `==`,no `=`, y además no puedes comparar un valor `string` con `0`, que es un entero.

Answer (score 10):

Esta linea esta muy rara

```
string Puerto = ("SerialPort1.ReadLine()").ToString();
```

los string no se evaluan en c#, no se porque has escrito el `ReadLine` entre comillas

```
private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    string line = SerialPort1.ReadLine();

    int puerto = Convert.ToInt32(line);

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("El valor actual es de {0}", line));

}
```

ademas tampoco necesitas usar un `if` para cambiar el mensaje

[SerialPort.ReadLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Has definido Puerto como string y luego haces una comparación con un Int. Solo puedes hacer comparaciones de objetos del mismo ambito. Si no quieres cambiar tu código basta con añadir unas comillas a los números que están dentro de la comparación y cambiar el signo = a ==.

```
string Puerto = ("SerialPort1.ReadLine()").ToString();
if (Puerto == "0") {
    MessageBox.Show("El valor actual es de 0");
}
else if (Puerto == "1") {
    MessageBox.Show("El valor actual es de 1");
}
else if (Puerto == "2") {
    MessageBox.Show("El valor actual es de 2");
}
else if (Puerto == "3") {
    MessageBox.Show("El valor actual es de 3");
}
```

Con esto te funionará perfectamente aunque te sugiero que hagas lo que te ha dicho Leandro. Este ejemplo es para que veas el porqué no te funcionaba.